# How to use blat tool for searching a gene in the genome?

Tags: search, genome, blat

I need to work with blat tool. I need to find the start and end positions of some genes in the genome. I downloaded the tool from the link below:
http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQblat.html , a blat file + blatSrc.zip file.
I dont know how to run it. The user guide can be found in the link below:
http://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/blatSpec.html

Can anyone tell me please which command I have to write to get my result ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The basic command is:
blat database query output.psl

For example if you want to search for a specific sequence in the human genome your command might be:
blat hg19.fa query_sequence.fa output.psl

See more details here:
http://genome.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/help/blatSpec.html